# Simple popup window

Tags: ios, react-native

How can I create a popup window like the alert method does?
This was the question. Stack Overflow says my question do not meet the quality standards. Maybe they mean this question is to short. So I write this text, because all is said with this question.

Comment: It's not about the length of the question text, it's about being detailed about what you want to achieve and what you have tried. Showing that you have done some research and you are stuck at some point, or need help to decide between alternate solutions. The reviewers are real people, not a machine.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. And I think it's the length. How should a javascript detect how detailed a question is? Do you have some useful information relating to my question?

Comment: The questions are moderated by humans. That is why your question got flagged. As @DavideR. has stated it is about the quality of your question and the more detail you provide will mean you will be more likely to get higher quality answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AlertIOS` to call the alert window and display properties depending on what you'd like to show.

There are also a few modal libraries available, such as [this one](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-modal)